# Using Webservice to send username and password from PHP to JAVA Api

Tags: java, php, web-services

I've gone through many sites and found out webservice is the one way to send the values(username and password) securely from one server to the other server.

In my Php Application i've to send my username and password from php page (vehicle.php) to the java api page (someheader://someip:someport/track/Track?page=map.fleet). That Api should accept the username and password ,verify them and login.

My problem is i dont know how to send a request with username and password to this Java Api from php page through webservice. Please help me guys.

Thanks,

SJ

Comment: [PHP WebService Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php)

Comment: There are many different authentication methods used to lock down a WebService with a Username and Password. We have no idea which one the Java WebService you are consuming is using and until we do will not be able to help you. It could be [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), you may have to hit a URL to get an Api Token, or maybe something else. Does the Java Web Service have any documentation explaining how you should send the username and password?  Or can you get this information from the author of the Java Api?

Comment: @theon am using OpenGts Api http://www.opengts.org/

Comment: @HOSTGUY I can't find any indication of a WebService or API in the documentation on that site, let alone what authentication method it uses. Are you definitely using an API and not just requesting the HTML pages generated by the OpenGts application?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/restful-web-service-tutorial-introduction-rest-restful/) tutorial should point you in the right direction.

Don't forget to [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) your passwords before sending them around.

Comment: @npiti i tried the Restful webservice link you have asked me to refer, it sends the request and am getting the response too but i dont know how to display the response webpage to my browser. If i simply put echo $response  it displays a page from the api without any css and proper links.

Comment: @HOSTGUY: The purpose of webservices for the two applications to communicate. If you want the result of that communication (user name, password, etc) to be made visible in a webpage, you would need to call the services and then render any data yielded yourself.

Comment: @npiti yes i called a function name $getresponse which is inside the webservice after that i echoed tat response variable, it just echoes the values from the api page without any css.

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't know how to send to send request to web service. First test those services using tools like storm, SOAPUI. Here you will get an idea of what inputs are to be passed and what's output. The least you should know what's the format (XML) of request.